# Passing data from an echo dropdown list using javascript

Tags: php

I have this dropdown list that is written using `echo` 
But the select is not as expected

This is my select tag

```
 $output.=" <select name='selectnewauthor' id='selectnewauthor' class='form-control input-lg selectnewauthor'>
    <option disabled selected value>Select Author</option> ";


 // Getting data from database
 $getresourcetype = "Book";                 
 $selectqry = "SELECT author_fullname FROM tbl_author_add WHERE resource_type = ? ORDER BY author_fullname";
 $stmt_author = $mysqlconnection->prepare($selectqry);
 $stmt_author->bind_param("s",$getresourcetype);
 $stmt_author->execute();
 $stmt_author->store_result();
 $stmt_author->bind_result($author_fullname);

 // Writing options
 while($stmt_author->fetch()) {
    $author_fullname = $author_fullname;
    $output .= "<option value='{$author_fullname}'>{$author_fullname}</option>";
 }
 $output.="</select>
```

Comment: See [*mvce*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I'd recommend just giving the parsed HTML output so we can run your code. There are a bunch of possible reasons why this can happen.

Comment: `$author_fullname = $author_fullname;` wat

Comment: @Tyr - that was what I thought but then I saw this `$stmt_author->bind_result($author_fullname);`

Comment: its the row that is being fetch from my table

Comment: the dropdown is being populated correctly.

Comment: could you share the generated HTML?

Comment: It still makes no sense in this context.

Comment: try remove `$author_fullname = $author_fullname;`. the variable is bind automaticaly why do you need to re-assign it ?

Comment: still nothing mate

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though your `#selectnewauthor` element is dynamically-generated. As such, you need to attach the listener to an element available on page load, and make use of **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**.

Essentially, instead of `$("#selectnewauthor").on('change', function() ...`
You're looking for `$("document").on("change", "#selectnewauthor", function() ...`.

Comment: ill give it a try !